Apple Pay recurring payment with MPGS
Looking to see if someone have experience with integrating Apple Pay with with Mastercard Payment Gateway? Specifically for recurring / Merchant Initiated Transactions (MIT)?
We were able to configure our gateway with the appropriate payment processing certificate and get one-off payments working by sending the paymentToken data to the transaction API by setting it to the field: sourceOfFunds.provided.card.devicePayment.paymentToken
What stumped us is when it came to recurring payments. After the paymentToken has been created on device with the appropriate parameters, what do we do with this payload?
After making a Customer Initiated Transaction (CIT) we get no usable reference back to be able to make subsequent MITs.
Upon trolling through Apple docs, it looks like if we decode the token, we will be able to get the merchantTokenIdentifier which I think it's a reference to the scheme token, not sure if we could then use this for subsequent MITs?
Looking at other payment gateways like Stripe or Braintree it seems like they support vaulting of mobile wallets out of the box, but we couldn't find anything specific for MPGS.

It has been confirmed that at the time of writing CommWeb does not support gateway tokenisation for scheme tokens - I know the terminology is confusing, but it's essentially what we were trying to achieve.
Tho we have been told this feature is in testing in MPGS and should hopefully be supported soon.
